# In angular 2 material design, md-slide-toggle is not working

Tags: angular

How to solve this issue,i am not getting the proper output.so below is my code.

This is app component.

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template: `
       <md-slide-toggle>
         Slide Toggle
       </md-slide-toggle>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {



    }
```

i have installed these and configured.

```
    npm install --save @angular/material

    npm install --save hammerjs 

    npm install --save-dev @types/hammerjs

    but how to configure this in system js(I am using cli to generate project and was not able to find systemjs file).

    System.config({
      // existing configuration options
      map: {
        ...,
        '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js'
      }
    });
```

See below image

[image: This image is output]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a theme for the slide toggles to look right. There is a guide [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/docs/theming.md) on how to get started by using one of the prebuilt themes.

Comment: zone.js:1382GET http://localhost:4200/~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css 404 (Not Found)

Comment: when i add deeppurple-amber.css to app.component.css it is showing 404 not found error.                                                                                               zone.js:1382GET http://localhost:4200/~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If you are using angular-cli move it would be best to move deeppurple-amber.scss into the src folder. Change the import statement on the first line of the file to be `@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';`. Then add the file to the styles sections of angular-cli.json. The theme will then get built by the cli.